# ovals in tabular

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

Need ovals in the tab:

```
\documentclass[9pt,handout,compress,rgb]{beamer}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|ccc}
& $M_1$ & \cdots & $M_n$\\
\hline\\
$W_1$  &   &   & \\
\vdots & & \ddots  &  \\
$W_m$ &   &  & 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I want the following (with narrower ovals):

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a possibility using `nicematrix` and `TikZ` with libraries `fit` (for fit) and `shapes.geometric` (for elliptical nodes). You can adjust the ellipses by changing `minimum size=` in `myellipse`.

Remember to compile twice when using `nicematrix`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[9pt,handout,compress,rgb]{beamer}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\tikzset{myellipse/.style={draw, red, very thick, ellipse, fit=#1, minimum size=3mm, inner sep=0pt}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
\begin{NiceArray}{c|ccc}
& M_1 & \cdots & M_n\\
\hline\\
W_1  &   &   & \\
\vdots & & \ddots  &  \\
W_m &   &  & 
\CodeAfter
     \begin{tikzpicture}
     \node[myellipse=(3-|2.5)(5.5-|2.5)] {};
     \node[myellipse=(3-|4.5)(5.5-|4.5)] {};
     \node[myellipse=(3.5-|2.5)(3.5-|4.5)] {};
     \node[myellipse=(5.5-|2.5)(5.5-|4.5)] {};
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceArray}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```